# powershell - empty list of group's members

Tags: powershell, csv

i'm trying to export to csv file list (or table but for now it doesn't matter) with the members of a group .
after many searches and i tried :

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity **genericGroupName** -recursive | select name | Export-csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

i also tried to change some things in this command- remove the `-recursive` .

i tried to find the problem in the command and remove the `-Export-csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation`

but it showed nothing (in nothing i mean - show my command and then nothing)

**my problem is that i got the output.csv , but it is empty.**

if it matters : 
the genericGroupName is actually :

```
$group = (Get-ADUser -Identity userName -properties MemberOf | select memberOf).memberOf
```

and

```
genericGroupName --> $group[0]
```

this command works well.

Comment: Use divide and conquer -method. That is, remove sections from your command until you identify the problematic part. For example, what happens if you just don't include the ` | Export-csv` part?

Comment: i already tried this , i got nothing. i will edit my post ti clear that i tried this before posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem (accidentally) by closing the powershell ISE and then open it. 
I am still don't know what was the problem but somehow it fixed by closing the powershell